# Android: Cannot resolve symbol 'GeofenceTransitionsIntentService'

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am trying to implement a feature for adding and monitoring geofences. I tried to do it by this [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html) but I'm already stuck on the first step.

I have also checked build.gradle and I use the same compile and targetSdkVersion...

I have tried to add the service to my AndroidManifest file like they  described it but unfortunately when I add this service tag, it's name is displayed in red color and I get this message:

> Cannot resolve symbol 'GeofenceTransitionsIntentService'
>   Validates resource references inside Android XML files.

[image]

This is how my AndroidManifest.xml looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="at.at.tuwien.hci.hciss2015">

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".InitActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".CharActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_char">
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".AnimationSampleActivity">
    </activity>

    <service android:name=".GeofenceTransitionsIntentService" />
</application>
```

Does anybody know what causes this issue and how can I fix it?

Comment: What is your `targetSdkVersion` and what about your `AndroidManifest`? Please post some code.

Comment: Looks like your `GeofenceTransitionsIntentService` does not exists at your root package.

Comment: I have also uploaded my manifest

Comment: What is your packageName? What is the package of your `GeofenceTransitionsIntentService.java` file? Looks to me like they missmatch.

Comment: BTW, **never** post your API keys and try to put them in `strings.xml` to avoid recovery from decompilation... #security

Comment: sorry I have uploaded it again. my package as you can see it in my manifest file is `package="at.at.tuwien.hci.hciss2015"`

Comment: I asked about two packages, you only answered one. Your application packageName is `at.at.tuwien.hci.hciss2015`, right. What is the `package` or your `GeofenceTransitionsIntentService.java`?

Comment: I am sorry for this missunderstanding, I have not implemented it yet. I have seen it now in the tutorial that it is an custom IntentService class. I guess as soon as I implement it, this will bi solved by itself

Comment: I posted a clear answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `GeofenceTransitionsIntentService.java` file obviously has not your root package.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="at.at.tuwien.hci.hciss2015">
```

Your `GeofenceTransitionsIntentService.java` should start with:

```
package at.at.tuwien.hci.hciss2015;

// ...
```

Then you can declare it in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<service android:name=".GeofenceTransitionsIntentService" />
```

Here the `.GeofenceTransitionsIntentService` implies that `GeofenceTransitionsIntentService` in at the root of your package, which is `at.at.tuwien.hci.hciss2015`.

Answer (score 1):

You need the full path to the service. Change it to look like this:

```
<service android:name="com.myproject.GeofenceTransitionsIntentService"/>
```

Where `com.myproject` is the appropriate package name.

Comment: Wrong, look at https://developer.android.com/samples/Geofencing/Application/AndroidManifest.html

Comment: Only if it is in the root. If it can't find it in the root then he needs the full package name.

Comment: Then again, the full packageName would not be necessary. You could have `<service android:name=".services.GeofenceTransitionsIntentService" />` AFAIK

Comment: If it is indeed under the `at.at.tuwien.hci.hciss2015` package name. But according to the last comment he hasn't even implemented the class yet so there's the problem right there.

Comment: Right, your `com.myproject` got me into thinking you thought the full package name was required. Problem was indeed bad package, not that it was not full. `com.example.android.wearable.geofencing` is the package used in the sample code from Google, not `com.myproject`. But I'm sure you were right too.