# importing com.google.android.gms.location.Geofence causing "cannot resolve symbol Geofence" in AS

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-geofence

I'm trying to use the Geofence API to create a geofence that causes a push notification on the user's phone when they enter the geofence. I'm trying for now to just hard code the geofence around a particular latitude and longitude and there are a lot of great tutorials for that but I'm having an issue in my imports in my project.

```
import com.google.android.gms.location.Geofence;
import com.google.android.gms.location.GeofencingRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.location.GeofencingApi;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
```

Geofence and the like are appearing in red and the error is saying "Cannot resolve symbol 'Geofence'

I've followed the instructions on the tutorials and have

```
<service android:name="com.skoovy.android.GeofenceTransitionsIntentService" />
```

in my manifest. I'm using AS latest version. I know I'm probably going to feel silly when someone gives me an answer but I just can't figure this out. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have the related jar as dependency?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30918658/android-cannot-resolve-symbol-geofencetransitionsintentservice

Comment: I had looked for a jar but didn't immediately fine one, is that probably the issue?
mrdeveloper I've read through that thread but that is not the same problem I am having. Thank you though

Comment: Do you have the dependency listed in your build.gradle file? If so, do you have any conflicting dependencies?

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, have you resolved it!